# QGIS 3: How to set Print Layout Size above A4/Legal?

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer, printing

QGis Layout Manager does not show page size above A4

Menu Layout > Page Setup

Composition cannot be created for bigger format

[image]

Customize size is rejected

QGIS versions tested: 3.4, 3.10

Comment: Sounds like a bug that would be worthy to report.

Comment: Issue reported but not considered as a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug or a confusing workflow to define the layout size.

### Workaround 1

A way I've found to circumvent this issue is to select the Layout>Print Menu (Ctrl+P)
An there to change the printer to the PDF printer.

[image: Printer Menu]

In order to force the printer selection I have needed to launch a print.

Page sizes up to A0 are then available for me in the Layout Manager

### Workaround 2

Tested on a single configuration on QGIS 3.10 (*generalization needs to be confirmed*)

- Set any page size
- **Right Click** in the print layout canvas (in main view)
- A **contextual menu** appears under the cursor, select *Page properties*
- From there a page appears in
  "Item Properties" where you can redefine the page size.

*Note*: if you have created multiple pages, **This is the menu** to find and use to remove a page
(Antogonist action of
[image: Add Pages ...])

Ref: [Qgis User Guide > Layout Panel.](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/overview_composer.html#layout-panel)